# React: It is a performance drag to have elements displayed by conditional on every loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I'm considering two setups for a large list of data elements. Each element can be pressed to pull up a modal that will contain details for the element. In one version I only have one modal and it is told which element is selected by a parent state. In the other version each element has its own modal that is permanently assigned an id during each loop. I like the simplicity of having the ids built into each modal (no worries about state-related race conditions etc), but I don't know if it's a performance drag to have all those conditionally-shown modals on a page at once. Here are two simple examples of what I'm talking about:

In the first version there is only one modal, and it is told which element is currently selected by what is stored in the parent state:

```
function Page() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false)
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState()

  function elementSelected(id) {
    setSelectedId(id)
    setShowModal(true)
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {largeGlobalSet.map({id} => <Element key={id} onPress={() => elementSelected(id)} />)}
      {showModal && <Modal id={selectedId} />}
    </View>
  )
}
```

In the other version, each element has its own modal which is permanently assigned an id that matches it to the element.

```
function Page() {
  return (
    <View>
      {largeGlobalSet.map({id} => <ElementWithModal key={id} id={id} />)}
    </View>
  )
}

function ElementWithModal({id}) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <View>
      <Element onPress={() => setShowModal(true)}>
      {showModal && <Modal id={id} />}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Depending on modal implementation it is likely a wash. Many modal implementations use a react portal and inject a single node into the DOM from which to display a modal so it is a bit irrelevant if many components "fight" for the callback controlling modal visibility, or if they aren't and it's simply a race-condition and the last one to set it gets it. I've seen a few modal packages that *do* allow for multiple modals to be open at once, but these will use more portals or injected DOM nodes. What is the modal solution in your code snippets?

Comment: I didn't actually mean for the fact that the attached element is a modal to become relevant information, but that was my fault for leaving that door open. I should have just named it <Element2 /> or something because I'm more just asking if it's a problem to have a conditionally shown element on every loop so that I know for any generic case in the future. But to answer your question, I'm using React Native Paper, so in my real code I have a <Portal /> around each modal as well. And I use the visibibility prop on the modal rather than a conditional.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry about that. In this case I think the answer is no, this pattern alone shouldn't adversely affect performance. React does all it's diffing in a virtual DOM it maintains; it can see if `showModal` (or whatever the condition is) has changed or not if it is part of a component state or passed as a prop. The render function is a pure function, so as long as neither state or props change, then the output isn't the same, react will simply return the last rendered output.

Comment: If interested, you can do a shallow dive into [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), which can lead a deeper dive if you choose to read the linked docs from there.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the info and the link. @DrewReese

Comment: Shoot, typo... "so as long as neither state or props change, then the output ***is*** the same, react will simply return the last rendered output."